# Integral equality $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\dots = \int_{|t|\le \delta}\dots+\int_{\delta\le |t|\le \pi}\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

This is an excerpt from [here (page 6, bottom)](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/articles/fejer_theorem.pdf)

> [image]

I don't know if this is a typo or not, but what exactly happened to the integral of $\int_{-\pi}^{-\delta}$ for the $|\sigma_n(x) - f(x)|$? I don't understand the equality.

Comment: look at $|t|$. The inequality $\delta\le|t|\le\pi$ describes both $-\pi\le t\le-\delta$ and $\delta\le t\le\pi$

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko, oh wow I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two integrals at the bottom are over $|t|<\delta$ and $\delta\le|t|\le\pi$ respectively. The first inequality restricts $t$ to the range $(-\delta,\delta)$, and the second restricts $t$ to a union of two ranges: $[-\pi,-\delta]\cup[\delta,\pi]$. The integrals shown would correspond to three integrals, if upper and lower limits of integration were indicated:  $\displaystyle\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\cdots dt $ for the first one, and  $\displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{-\delta}\cdots dt $ + $\displaystyle \int_\delta^{\pi}\cdots dt$ for the second one.

Comment: Looks like I missed that part.